# laravel как проверить произвелась ли запись в бд

Tags: php, laravel

Как проверить успех метода  `$dela->save();`?
   После успеха нужно выполнить:

```
$event=new Event();//add event data
     $event->type_id=1;//id delo_type
     $event->title=Auth::user()->name.' добавил новое дело - '.$dela->nazva;
     $event->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
     $event->save();
      return redirect()->route('profile.mydelo');
```

Comment: самый банальный способ, это взять известный уже `id`, сделать запрос в бд по этому `id` и если он там есть то сделай то что нужно

Comment: Лучше использовать [saveOrFail](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_saveOrFail), который выбросит исключение в случае ошибки сохранения, и следующей линией после saveOrFail поставить нужный redirect, а в catch - вывод ошибки или её обработка.

Comment: даже интересно стало, зачем же указанный метод возвращает булевый результат.

Comment: @teran мне тоже стало интересно. Судя по всему, можно настроить листенер, который не даст сохранить и вернёт ложь. Здесь явно не тот случай

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую переписать так:

Сначала идем в модедь User и добавляем отношение к делу если у вас 1 пользователь имеет много дел то так

```
public function delos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Delo');
    }
```

затем:

```
$event = auth()->user()->delos()->create([
    'type_id' => 1,
    'title' => auth()->user()->name.' добавил новое дело - '.$dela->nazva
]);
```

теперь уже проверка, на не null/false если запись не будет создана, если не нравится код выше - оставляй как есть у тебя просто добавь эту проверку:

```
if(!$event){
    //тут редирект или просто выкидывай ошибку например 404
    //так же можешь записывать через фасад лог ошибку для обработки
    abort(404);
}
 //если запись все же была создана то возвращай профиль дело

return redirect()->route('profile.mydelo');
```

Answer (score -4):

**Не надо ничего проверять**

Это колупание в песочке с проверками уже сто лет как не используется, и тем более в современном фреймворке.

В случае ошибки при сохранении будет выброшено исключение, которое прервёт выполнение скрипта.

Поэтому **просто пиши свой код как есть.** В случае успеха он выполнится. В случае неуспеха не выполнится.

Никакой код для обработки ошибки **тоже писать не надо**, он в Laravel **уже есть**.

Comment: Проверять нужно, в меру, конечно, но нужно, без этого не будет ветвления и проверки на ошибки, исключения и важные детали, которые код отдает в результате исполнения, будут упущены.

Comment: не нужно. автор вопроса четко сказал- чтобы код ниже не исполнялся. Он и не будет. Вопрос решён. И уж тем более не надо свой типичный говнокод вкрячивать для проверки. Фреймфорк тем и ценен что раз в 500 умнее среднестатистического пхп юзера и сам всё сделает правильно

Comment: Код ниже save будет исполнятся в любом случае, так как нет проверки его булева результата; минимальная проверка в виде if($event->save()) это исключит.

Comment: Тут я могу только тяжело вздохнуть. РНР - это два мира.Один это говнокод образца конца 20 века с ручным проверками, а второй - прекрасный современный язык программирования, который поддерживает современные средства разработки, например исключения. И конечно же пользователю первого пхп никогда не понять код написанный на втором. "Как так! Я проверку не писал, а код не исполняется! Шайтан! Сгинь нечистая!". И даже тот факт, что условие всё равно никогда не выполнится, нашего троглодита не остановит. Условие должно быть и усё тут!

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/477822)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics не стоит заходить в очередь проверок, если не можешь понять вопрос

Comment: @Ипатьев, помимо непрофессионалов-троглодитов и профессионалов-нетроглодитов, есть ещё новички. для новичков упомяните, пожалуйста, в тексте ответа про исключение. спасибо!

Comment: пардоньте, но я, вот с laravel не знаком, но не вижу в документации, чтобы метод save на который тут брызгает слюной Ипатьев выбрасывал бы какое-либо исключение. вот у saveOrFail это документировано.

Comment: @teran ты суслика видишь? А он есть. Знание некоорых принципов избавляет от необходиости помнить множество фактов или рыться в документации. Любое вменяемое ПО кидает исключение при ошибке. Это конечно трудно понять адепту стиля "если муэскуэль нум ровс больше ноля...", так что придется просто поверить. а saveOrFail  вообще не об этом.

Comment: @Ипатьев вменяемое ПО обычно имеет вменяемую документацию. Вменяемый разработчик эту документацию обычно читает. То что внутри всплывет исключение от ПДО и ежу понятно. Может ли потребоваться обрабатывать ошибки валидации при необходимости, наверное, да. Может ли метод вернуть false, при соответствующем срабатывании события saving, вообще не доходя до БД, очевидно тоже может. Так что вместо говнокомментов хамоватой истерички пиши адекватные ответы.

Comment: @teran да, я быстро впадаю в истерику, когда вижу что неграмотность захлестывает. Ему в двух вопросах шесть человек стали писать ерунду. Меня это нервирует. Надо конечно держать себя вруках